# Numpy Create Diagonal Matrix with 2D Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a matrix

```
M = [1 2]                              
    [3 4]
```

and I want to create the 4x4 matrix:

```
[M 0]
[0 M]
=
[1 2 0 0]
[3 4 0 0]
[0 0 1 2]
[0 0 3 4]
```

How could I do this?
In general, how would I make a 2nx2n matrix with n copies of M along the diagonal?

This is the solution I came up with so far, but its pretty ugly.

```
def diag(m, n):
    return np.row_stack(tuple(
                   np.column_stack(tuple(m if i == j else np.zeros(m.shape)
                                         for i in range(n)))
                   for j in range(n)))
```